# Indicore 3 EMA Trading Strategy coding

Tags: lua, trading

If someone could please help, that would be great! I'm fairly new to coding, but am trying to create a basic automated trading strategy in Indicore 3, which uses LUA script. Even if you don't know much about trading, you could probably still recognize where I've gone wrong in this code.

Basically I'm trying to automate a buy into a trade when price, is above the FastEMA, the FastEMA is above the MedEMA, and the MedEMA is above the SlowEMA. And a sell trade in the exactly opposite fashion. I'm then wanting to close the trade when, in a buy situation, the Fast EMA is no longer above the MedEMA, and for a sell, the FastEMA rises above the MedEMA.

Plus, if the currency is already in a trade, I don't want it to put another one on. Hence the idea around the HaveTrades function.

Please if you have any idea, give me a shout. Like I say I'm a beginner, however I feel like this is a pretty basic code.
[Picture is to illustrate idea. Blue line is FastEMA, Green line is MedEMA, and Red line is SlowEMA.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyUT.png)

I used the original code off a 3EMA Indicore tutorial, and have tried to simplify it to what I need, so if there's inconsistencies with the code, please highlight them to me.

```
function Init()
strategy:name("3EMA test AMI");
strategy:description("No description");
strategy:requiredSource(core.Bar);
strategy:type(core.both);

strategy.parameters:addInteger("FastEMA", "Fast EMA", "No description", 5);
strategy.parameters:addInteger("MedEMA", "Medium Ema", "No description", 20);
strategy.parameters:addInteger("SlowEMA", "Slow EMA", "No description", 50);


strategy.parameters:addGroup("Trading Parameters");
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("AllowTrade", "Allow strategy to trade", "", false);
strategy.parameters:setFlag("AllowTrade", core.FLAG_ALLOW_TRADE);
strategy.parameters:addString("Account", "Account to trade on", "", "");
strategy.parameters:setFlag("Account", core.FLAG_ACCOUNT);
strategy.parameters:addInteger("Amount", "Trade Amount in Lots", "", 1, 1, 100);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("SetLimit", "Set Limit Orders", "", false);
strategy.parameters:addInteger("Limit", "Limit Order in pips", "", 30, 1, 10000);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("SetStop", "Set Stop Orders", "", false);
strategy.parameters:addInteger("Stop", "Stop Order in pips", "", 30, 1, 10000);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("TrailingStop", "Trailing stop order", "", false);

strategy.parameters:addGroup("Notification");
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("ShowAlert", "Show Alert", "", true);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("PlaySound", "Play Sound", "", false);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("RecurrentSound", "Recurrent Sound", "", false);
strategy.parameters:addFile("SoundFile", "Sound File", "", "");
strategy.parameters:setFlag("SoundFile", core.FLAG_SOUND);
strategy.parameters:addBoolean("SendEmail", "Send Email", "", false);
strategy.parameters:addString("Email", "Email", "", "");
strategy.parameters:setFlag("Email", core.FLAG_EMAIL);
end

local FastEMA;
local MedEMA;
local SlowEMA;
local EnableStage1TimeRange;
local TimeRangeStart;
local TimeRangeEnd;
local gSource = nil; -- the source stream
local PlaySound;
local RecurrentSound;
local SoundFile;
local Email;
local SendEmail;
local AllowTrade;
local Account;
local Amount;
local BaseSize;
local SetLimit;
local Limit;
local SetStop;
local Stop;
local TrailingStop;
local Offer;
local CanClose;
local iEMAFast;
local iEMAMed;
local iEMASlow;


function Prepare(nameOnly)
FastEMA = instance.parameters.FastEMA;
MedEMA = instance.parameters.MedEMA;
SlowEMA = instance.parameters.SlowEMA;
LookBack = instance.parameters.LookBack;
EnableStage1TimeRange = instance.parameters.EnableStage1TimeRange;
TimeRangeStart = instance.parameters.TimeRangeStart;
TimeRangeEnd = instance.parameters.TimeRangeEnd;


local name = profile:id() .. "(" .. instance.bid:instrument() .. ", " .. tostring(FastEMA) .. ", " .. tostring(MedEMA) .. ", " .. tostring(SlowEMA) .. ", " .. tostring(LookBack).. ", " .. tostring(EnableStage1TimeRange) .. ")";
instance:name(name);

if nameOnly then
    return ;
end

ShowAlert = instance.parameters.ShowAlert;

PlaySound = instance.parameters.PlaySound;
if PlaySound then
    RecurrentSound = instance.parameters.RecurrentSound;
    SoundFile = instance.parameters.SoundFile;
else
    SoundFile = nil;
end
assert(not(PlaySound) or (PlaySound and SoundFile ~= ""), "Sound file must be specified");

SendEmail = instance.parameters.SendEmail;
if SendEmail then
    Email = instance.parameters.Email;
else
    Email = nil;
end
assert(not(SendEmail) or (SendEmail and Email ~= ""), "E-mail address must be specified");


AllowTrade = instance.parameters.AllowTrade;
if AllowTrade then
    Account = instance.parameters.Account;
    Amount = instance.parameters.Amount;
    BaseSize = core.host:execute("getTradingProperty", "baseUnitSize", instance.bid:instrument(), Account);
    Offer = core.host:findTable("offers"):find("Instrument", instance.bid:instrument()).OfferID;
    CanClose = core.host:execute("getTradingProperty", "canCreateMarketClose", instance.bid:instrument(), Account);
    SetLimit = instance.parameters.SetLimit;
    Limit = instance.parameters.Limit * instance.bid:pipSize();
    SetStop = instance.parameters.SetStop;
    Stop = instance.parameters.Stop * instance.bid:pipSize();
    TrailingStop = instance.parameters.TrailingStop;
end

gSource = ExtSubscribe(1, nil, instance.parameters.TF, true, "bar"); 
tSource = ExtSubscribe(2, nil, "t1", true, "bar"); 
--TODO: Find indicator's profile, intialize parameters, and create indicator's instance (if needed)
iEMAFast = core.indicators:create("EMA", gSource.close, FastEMA)
iEMAMed = core.indicators:create("EMA", gSource.close, MedEMA)
iEMASlow = core.indicators:create("EMA", gSource.close, SlowEMA)
end


local Stage1Status = "Neutral"; -- possible values are "Neutral", "Buy", "Sell"


-- update indicators
iEMAFast:update(core.UpdateLast);
iEMAMed:update(core.UpdateLast);
iEMASlow:update(core.UpdateLast);

-- check for data
--if not iEMAFast.DATA:hasData(period) or not iEMAMed.DATA:hasData(period) or not 
 iEMAMed.DATA:hasData(period) then
    --core.host:trace("Not Enough Data. Checking Next Bar...")
    --return;
--end

-- close of bar, Stage 1, making sure EMAs are lined up.
if not haveTrades() then
    
    -- buy setup, if Price > Fast > Med > Slow 
    if gSource.close[period] > iEMAFast.DATA[period] and
        iEMAFast.DATA[period] > iEMAMed.DATA[period] and
        iEMAMed.DATA[period] > iEMASlow.DATA[period] then
        Status="Buy" 
        enter("B")
    end

    
    -- sell setup, if Price < Fast < Med < Slow 
    if gSource.close[period] < iEMAFast.DATA[period] and
        iEMAFast.DATA[period] < iEMAMed.DATA[period] and
        iEMAMed.DATA[period] < iEMASlow.DATA[period] then
        Status="Sell"
        enter("S")
    end

end




end

-- open positions in direction BuySell
function enter(BuySell)

local valuemap, success, msg;
valuemap = core.valuemap();

valuemap.OrderType = "OM";
valuemap.OfferID = Offer;
valuemap.AcctID = Account;
valuemap.Quantity = Amount * BaseSize;
valuemap.BuySell = BuySell;
valuemap.GTC = "GTC";

if SetLimit then
    -- set limit order
    valuemap.PegTypeLimit = "O";
    if BuySell == "B" then
       valuemap.PegPriceOffsetPipsLimit = Limit/instance.bid:pipSize();
    else
       valuemap.PegPriceOffsetPipsLimit = -Limit/instance.bid:pipSize();
    end
end

if SetStop then
    -- set stop order
    valuemap.PegTypeStop = "O";
    if BuySell == "B" then
       valuemap.PegPriceOffsetPipsStop = -Stop/instance.bid:pipSize();
    else
       valuemap.PegPriceOffsetPipsStop = Stop/instance.bid:pipSize();
    end
    
    if TrailingStop then
        valuemap.TrailStepStop = 1;
    end
end

if (not CanClose) and (StopLoss > 0 or TakeProfit > 0) then
    valuemap.EntryLimitStop = "Y"
end

success, msg = terminal:execute(100, valuemap);

if not(success) then
    terminal:alertMessage(instance.bid:instrument(), instance.bid[instance.bid:size() - 1], "open order failure: " .. msg, instance.bid:date(instance.bid:size() - 1));
    return false;
end

return true;
end
-- return true if trade is found (can check single side as well)
function haveTrades(BuySell)
local enum, row;
local found = false;
enum = core.host:findTable("trades"):enumerator();
row = enum:next();
while (not found) and (row ~= nil) do
    if row.AccountID == Account and
       row.OfferID == Offer and
       (row.BS == BuySell or BuySell == nil) then
       found = true;
    end
    row = enum:next();
end

return found;
end
-- Close trigger
function close(CanClose)
if HaveTrades and (Status == "Buy") and FastEMA<MedEMA then
    Status = "close" 
   
end

if HaveTrades and (Status == "Sell") and FastEMA>MedEMA then
    Status = "close"

end
end
```

Comment: I cannot see where you have defined `strategy`. It should either be a variable defined and initiated before the function `Init`, so that it has `name` and other "methods"; or passed to in as a parametre (so far, it has none), or defined and initiated in the beginning of the function body.
The definition and initiation could look like this: `local strategy = some_function()`.

Comment: If a function call has only one parametre, and it is a string or a table, you can omit the parentheses for better readability: `strategy:name("3EMA test AMI")` → `strategy:name'3EMA test AMI'`.

Comment: Also, it is not clear, where `instance`, `profile` and `core` come from.
`iEMAMed.DATA:hasData(period) then` dangles with everyting nearby commented out, and it will cause a syntax error.

Comment: `function Prepare(nameOnly)` uses many variables like `FastEMA` defined outside of it, making that function a *closure* with *upvalues*. I am not sure that it was your intention. Since the initial values for those variables are set in `Prepare`, and the variables don't seem to be used outside the function, it would be better to move them inside.

Comment: Also, I recommend to use indentation consistently. It will make your code more readable, even to you.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I'll try and implement all of your input here. It's really appreciated - as I had no idea where to stat looking for the errors.